# Laravel storing data after chuncking them

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables

- Companies
- Coupons
- Categories

Company table contains

- id, name, logo

category contains

- id, title,  logo

coupons contains

- id, title, terms, company_id, category_id

the last two are for relation ship between company, category modal and coupons modal.

After that being said, here is the case:

I have sent a request to my server using API that contains **Company_id**.

What I want to do is get all coupons that contain this Company_id, then from those coupons I want to take all Categories.

What I tried:

```
public function fetch_Categories($Company_id)
{
    //getting all coupons that containes the current company id
    $Coupons = Coupons::where('company_id' , $Company_id)->get();
   //Coupons variable returns two coupons which is expected 
    foreach($Coupons  as $Coupon){
        $Categroies = Categories::find($Coupon->category_id);
    }
}
```

ok you must have noticed the problem.

I am getting two coupons and in the future I will get more and I have to get the category from each one of them using category_id column, then return it using JSON as a collection of categories, but the question is how should I do that?

If it is not clear, I am getting two coupons and I should make foreach to store each category in my variable but when you put "=" sign then you will assign value for the variable and finally you will get one category which is the last one in the foreach. What I need is a way to store all the categories using the foreach and then return them to user using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one:

```
$categoryIds = Coupons::where('company_id', $Company_id)->pluck('category_id')->unique();
$categories = Categories::whereIn('id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

This is also more efficient than the foreach loop, as it only uses a single query to fetch all categories.

Comment: it is working perfectly thanks a lot friend i didn't know that where in gets all of records while where gets only one record so thanks a lot